# Uploading Image to S3 fails to complete upload

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I'm uploading an image to S3 and am having trouble completing the file transfer. Here is how the app acts.

1. Initiate `uploadToS3()`
2. File begins transfer sending bytes to server.
3. When around 600,000 bytes are sent, the upload halts.
4. After 20-40 seconds, the app continues its upload progress at 0%. It acts as if the file transfer never began in the first place.
5. During this entire time no errors appear in the logger.

In my view controller I have the following method that uploads the file.

```
func uploadToS3(){

    // get the image from a UIImageView that is displaying the selected Image
    var img: UIImage = imageView.image!

    // create a local image that we can use to upload to s3
    var path: NSString = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("image.png")
    var imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
    imageData.writeToFile(path as String, atomically: true)

    // once the image is saved we can use the path to create a local fileurl
    var url:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path as String)!

    // next we set up the S3 upload request manager
    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    // set the bucket
    uploadRequest?.bucket = "test-bucket"
    // I want this image to be public to anyone to view it so I'm setting it to Public Read
    uploadRequest?.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACL.PublicRead
    // set the image's name that will be used on the s3 server. I am also creating a folder to place the image in
    uploadRequest?.key = "foldername/image.png"
    // set the content type
    uploadRequest?.contentType = "image/png"
    // and finally set the body to the local file path
    uploadRequest?.body = url;

    // we will track progress through an AWSNetworkingUploadProgressBlock
    uploadRequest?.uploadProgress = {[unowned self](bytesSent:Int64, totalBytesSent:Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend:Int64) in

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            println("total  bytes sent")
            println(totalBytesSent)

            println("total  bytes expected to send")
            println(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
        })
    }

    // now the upload request is set up we can creat the transfermanger, the credentials are already set up in the app delegate
    var transferManager:AWSS3TransferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
    // start the upload
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithExecutor(BFExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock:{ [unowned self]
        task -> AnyObject in

        // once the uploadmanager finishes check if there were any errors
        if(task.error != nil){
            println("%@", task.error);
        }else{ // if there aren't any then the image is uploaded!
            // this is the url of the image we just uploaded
            println("https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3-demo-swift/foldername/image.png");
        }

        //self.removeLoadingView()
        println("all done");
        return ""
        })
}
```

### For anyone looking to recreate this app

Add to your Podfile:

```
pod 'AWSCore'
pod 'AWSS3'
pod 'AWSiOSSDKv2'
pod 'AWSCognitoSync'
```

Then add a bridge header containing:

```
#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>
#import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>
```

In my `AppDelegate` I have:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {        
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.initialize()

    var credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
        regionType: AWSRegionType.USEast1,
        identityPoolId: "identity pool id"
    )

    var configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
        region: AWSRegionType.USEast1,
        credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider
    )

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    return true
}
```

Finally, in the view controller that contains `uploadToS3()`, add `import AWSS3`.

### Update

Here is the last section of logged errors.

```
}]
2015-05-09 19:24:24.540 CoolApp[4492:55681] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Verbose] AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:278 | -[AWSXMLResponseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body: [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>A03D405FC272808A</RequestId><HostId>bhSw+xQkGrMVd9QWMKMG1qYezPJet8b5L2ZIoGXePoftuupMP3HdgbAgCpStiLefo5yA3m1OJvY=</HostId></Error>]
(%@, Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain error 1.)" UserInfo=0x7c17cdc0 {HostId=bhSw+xQkGrMVd9QWMKMG1qYezPJet8b5L2ZIoGXePoftuupMP3HdgbAgCpStiLefo5yA3m1OJvY=, Code=AccessDenied, Message=Access Denied, RequestId=A03D405FC272808A})
all done
```

My question is, how do I fix this and have the image upload succesfully.

Comment: Do you see the same issue with [S3TransferManager-Sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples)? Have you made sure your Amazon S3 bucket is in US Standard Region?

Comment: Yes I'm having the same issue with the sample project. My bucket is in US Standard Region.

Comment: Have you enabled the [verbose logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html#logging)? What does the log tell you?

Comment: The log doesn't tell me anything out of the ordinary. No error pops up during that upload halt. Is there something specific I should be looking for?

Comment: Can you share the logs? It may help actually looking at them. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue with the sample app. I was able to upload/download an image file without any issues.

Comment: Sure, updated the question with the last line of code. This time it shows the error. Let me know if you want more output from the logs.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to implement this in Swift 2.0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states, the permission is not set up correctly with your Amazon Cognito Identity pool. [Understanding Amazon Cognito Authentication](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2UQN4KWI6GDJL/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication) blog series ([Part 2](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2FL1QAPDE0UAH/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-2-Developer-Authenticated-Ident), [Part 3](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies)) and [Amazon Cognito Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/) are your great resources for understanding and setting up Cognito Identity.

Comment: Bingo. I realized this was an IAM permissions issue.

Comment: @jason328 can you please share the exact solution that helped you with the issue. what permissions have you changed ?